# how to fix the following error for facebook android sdk integration using Phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, sdk

Please help to fix the following error. Currently trying to integrate Facebook Android SDK using PhoneGap.I have followed this tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlpBgWiel2w and github resources:https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.git
But got the bellow error:-

```
   Error in an XML file: aborting build.
   Error in an XML file: aborting build.
   Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
   Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
   Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
    Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
   Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
    Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
```

Comment: Make sure to clean your project. And please check if you are including the lib twice.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in **eclipse** and I did the following and it **worked** for me:

1- Right click your Android project
2- **Properties** >>> **Java Build Path**
3- Click on **Android Dependencies**
4- Click **Remove** >>> **OK**
5- Run Android project

Comment: Did everything from all the other advises, your solution works :) thanks for Sharing

Answer (score 2):

Its is a very easy fix though it seems to be very tough issue to solve.

```
1.Just make a copy of the project.
2.run the the copy of the project thats it!!!
```

As this steps worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but may have resolved it. In platforms/android, run:

```
find . -name "AsyncFacebookRunner.class"
```

For me, this found the class in both `platforms/android/ant-build/` and `platforms/android/FacebookLib/ant-build`. Since there will be a jar from FacebookLib, the class will end up multiple times. I managed to resolve this by making sure that Eclipse is closed and then removing all `bin`, `gen`, `ant-build`, and `ant-gen` directories from both `platforms/android` and `platforms/android/FacebookLib` and `platforms/android/CordovaLib` and then running the build command again. After that, the above find command only found one copy of the class, in `FacebookLib/ant-build`.