# Android Studio - App Crashing on AddThis.jar - "Sources Not Found" Message

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, addthis

I have a project using the AddThis SDK. I have added the AddThis.jar as a library to my project in Android Studio.

When I tap the button to Post to Facebook, the app crashes with this log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apploi/com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apploi/com.addthis.ui.activities.ATShareActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apploi/com.addthis.ui.activities.ATShareActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.showNextView(ATActivityGroup.java:167)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.loadViews(ATActivityGroup.java:99)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.onCreate(ATActivityGroup.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATShareActivity.onCreate(ATShareActivity.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.showNextView(ATActivityGroup.java:167)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.loadViews(ATActivityGroup.java:99)
            at com.addthis.ui.activities.ATActivityGroup.onCreate(ATActivityGroup.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Connection reset by peer
```

From what I can tell, this line is saying that the ATShareActivity is having problems.
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apploi/com.addthis.ui.activities.ATShareActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

When I navigate into `AddThis.jar` and open the `ATShareActivity` file (or any other file inside the jar file), a message appears at the top of the screen saying "Sources Not Found", with a clickable link titled `Attach Sources...`

I open the `Attach Sources...` link and it allows me to select a directory, but I don't know what I am supposed to do here.

Any ideas about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the documentation, it would appear that the AddThis SDK was written by someone without adequate Android development experience. That being said, it is an Android library project, not a JAR, and so you need to add it as an Android library project.

Comment: From the documentation:"The AddThis Android SDK is shipped as a library project, so you can add this to any android project as a library."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the tips. Here's what ended up finally working:

**1) Convert AddThis to Gradle**

`File > Import Project...`  to transition `AddThisSDK` to a Gradle Project. This created a new project, which I named `AddThisGradle`

**1B) If You Already have the Facebook SDK Installed**

Opened Terminal and navigated inside the new `AddThisGradle` directory to `AddThisGradle/app/libs`

Used command `zip -d addthis0.0.8.jar com/facebook/*` in Terminal to delete the Facebook files from `addthis0.0.8.jar`

Went back to `Android Studio`, checked that the Facebook directory disappeared from `AddThisGradle`

Went back to my my main project in `Android Studio`

**2) Add AddThis to Your Project**

Selected `File > Project Structure` in my main project in `Android Studio`

Pressed the `+` in the upper-left of the Project Structure screen.

The `New Module` screen appears

Selected `Import Existing Project` in the `New Module` screen

Selected `AddThisGradle` as the `source directory`

Checked the `import` checkbox

Changed the `module name` to `:addthis`

Click the `Finish` button

Wait for gradle to re-sync

**3) Add Dependency**

Back to the `Project Structure` screen

Select `app` in the left column of the `Project Structure` screen

Select the `Dependencies` tab

Click the `+` button at the bottom of the `Dependencies` tab screen

Select `+ > 3 Module Dependency`

The `Choose Module` screen appears

Select the `:addthis` Module

Wait for gradle to re-sync

**4) Keep Trying**

At this point, everything seemed good except when I tried to run the app I was getting an error that said `Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug’`. I used the first suggestion from this question to fix my problem: [Gradle Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' with new Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234895/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-with-new-android-studio-project)