# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, libgdx

I´ve seen lots of post about this issue, but none have solved mine so far.
I´ve "exploded" the facebook sdk and the support v4 into my project. And from what I can see I have facebookSDK.JAR located in my android project´s libs directory and in the "exploded" folder. Aswell as in the actual Facebook SDK project. Looking like this:

[image]

and build.gradle looks like this:
http://hastebin.com/oharoriyer.pl

Comment: This question has been asked a good few times. Have you tried the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15247670/1585773?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. Switch from Eclipse to Intellij. Don´t know why Eclipse was giving me that answer since I had looked through every possible reason.